# PHP Form to get filled only once

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have some list of pdf download option in my website. I like people to signup to download those pdf. Once they fill the signup form they get pdf link to their mail address. But the challenge am trying to achieve is next pdf download should not ask signup form, the link has to be sent directly to their email address.

Comment: Using cookies may come in handy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On sign up or sign in, you may set a COOKIE with their username or email address.

Read [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) how to create a cookie in PHP.

Next time when a user visits your site, you need to check whether the cookie exist. If it exist, get the username or the email address you store in it, and use this detail to send the email.

To check if a cookie is present,

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['cookie_name']))
{
// Cookie is present $data_in_cookie=$_COOKIE['cookie_name']
}
```

**But make sure you show it as a option and not a "forced-feature" to the user during the sign up process, with some thing similar to a checkbox with text, REMEMBER ME. Because your user may access your website from public computers such as Browsing cafe.**

Answer (score 0):

When you fill in any information and press button to submit form, save everything to COOKIE and next time check if there is COOKIE set and use it's information instead (allow to change information if needed).

Comment: @Kiran By writing some code. Use google for that too. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Answer (score 0):

For php [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp)

```
setcookie(name,value,duration); ex : setcookie('name','kiran',time()+60*24);
```

to set the cookie value and to retrive

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['name']))
$name = $_COOKIE['name'];
```